# Lightning input Number to Apex goes wrong

Tags: apex, lightning-aura-components, lightning

I have a lightning component which is a screen to check the timesheet entries of the employees. The supervisor can change the value of the timesheet(to fill gaps and stuff).

I have realised this by using a Lightning input type number. When a change happens in a row, I add this specific record to a list and this list is send to Apex to save when the user clicks the save-button.

When I click save, I logged the changed records and there everything is okay(for example 5.5), but when I debug in Apex, I see 55 as a value. So I don't understand why Apex transforms this in an Integer.

```
<lightning:input type="number" aura:id="field" step="any" name="{!emp.empId + ';' + day.dayId + ';' + entry.Id}" value="{!entry.Change_Supervisor__c}" variant = "label-hidden" onchange="{!c.handleEntryChange}"/>
```

Extra Information :

- I use Salesforce objects to display everything etc

Comment: Provide handler method and apex code

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some reason the Lightning Input changed the number to text. I discovered this when using Stringify. So now I just use a foreach to check if the value is NaN. If so, I cast it to a Number. That was the solution. But in fact this shouldn't be a problem...